# How to solve $\int \frac{a}{(a^{2}+x^{2})^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: integration

I tried the Euler substitution: $t=x+\sqrt{x^{2}+a}$ and I got $\int \frac{4ta}{(t^{2}+a)^{2}}dt$ and I don't know wnat now or if it is the right way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now use substitution $t^2+a=u$, $2tdt=du$

Comment: Try $x=a\tan y$

Comment: Substitute $$x=a\tan(t)$$

Comment: Or $x=a\sinh y$. Or integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substituting $$x=a\tan(t)$$ we get
$$a^2+x^2=a^2(1+\tan^2(t))$$ and $$dx=a(1+\tan^2(t))dt$$ thus our integral is
$$\int\frac{a^2(1+\tan^2(t))}{(a^2(1+\tan^2(t))^{3/2}}dt$$ this gives
$$|a|\int\sqrt{\frac{sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}}dt=\int\pm\frac{a}{\cos(t)}dt$$
note that $$\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}=\frac{\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}{\sin^2(t)}=1+\tan^2(t)$$

Comment: Could you give some more details? How did you get the numerator below "our integral is..."?

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: Yes, thank you ;)

Comment: i wish you all the best in the new year

Comment: The same to you ;)